# Ubuntu 20.04.2 PHP Error while pecl install

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install sqlsrv driver.

```
root@testapp:/# pecl install sqlsrv

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in PEAR/REST.php on line 187
PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /usr/share/php/PEAR/REST.php on line 187
```

**pecl** version information.

```
root@testapp:/# pecl version
PEAR Version: 1.10.9
PHP Version: 7.4.3
Zend Engine Version: 3.4.0
Running on: Linux test app 5.4.0-65-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:25:17 UTC 2021 x86_64
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried `mkdir -p /tmp/pear/cache` but still facing same error.

Comment: Hello, can you please include the last error message after `Notice: Trying to access ...`? Does it show something like `Error: cannot download "pecl/sqlsrv" Download failed install failed`? or `No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/sqlsrv"`

Answer (score 2):

1. If it says: "**No releases available for package ...**", you will need to install php-dev package to get the necessary PHP5 source files to compile additional modules.

   **Run** `apt-get install php-dev`

   You can specify specific version: `apt-get install php8.0-dev`
2. If you see "**make: not found**", you need to have `make` installed

   **Run** `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
3. If you see: "**WARNING: channel 'pecl.php.net**' has updated its protocols":

   **Run** `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net`
4. If you see: "**Missing sql.h**", you will need to install `unixodbc-dev` package.

   **Run** `apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev`

I'm guessing you're missing the last package, which is necessary for `pecl` command to install the PHP drivers.

If it still does not work, please update the complete error message.

You can refer to:

- [Linux and macOS Installation Tutorial for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP  for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-php-pecl/issues/14)
- [AskUbuntu: Install PECL Packages on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403327/install-pecl-packages-on-ubuntu)

Comment: We usually do not answer questions that have *nothing* to do with programming.